# How to change Intellij IDEA Project Navigator Layout

Tags: intellij-idea

My IntellJ project window switched the layout to horizontal (see picture), and I can't figure out how to get it back to "normal" where the folders are displayed vertically.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project is broken and missing modules. That horizontal bar has nothing to do with anything.

Answer (score 0):

The [IntelliJ documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/project-tool-window.html#views) has indepth guidelines with images to explain the different settings and its views

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if i understood right, but try to click on the arrow right next to "Project". There are diffrent views available. Try one of them :-)